# SQL Query for Parent Child Relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, hierarchical-data

I have db table with parent child relationship as:

```
NodeId    NodeName    ParentId
------------------------------
1         Node1       0
2         Node2       0
3         Node3       1
4         Node4       1
5         Node5       3
6         Node6       5
7         Node7       2
```

Here parentId = 0 means that it is a root level node. Now I want to write an SQL Query which will return child at all level of a parent category.

e.g. for nodeId = 1, it should return 3, 4, 5, 6.

I am using MS SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
with [CTE] as (
    select * from [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = 1
    union all
    select * from [CTE] p, [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = p.[NodeId]
)
select * from [CTE]
```

Comment: I suggest adding the maximum recursion hint.

Answer (score 6):

You should look into using the Nested Set Model for parent-child relationships within an SQL database. It's much nicer than trying to store the parentID of records in the table like this, and makes queries like this much easier.

Answer (score 4):

And just to make sure it works if its a parent of itself (otherwise it will recurse until it breaks):

```
   with [CTE] as (
        select * from [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = 1
        union all
        select * from [CTE] p, [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = p.[NodeId]
        and c.[ParentId] <> c.[NodeId]
    )
    select * from [CTE]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 WITH Temp_Menu AS
 ( 
  SELECT AM.* from FCB_AccessMenu AM where AM.[ParentId] = 6   

           UNION ALL     

        SELECT AM.* FROM  FCB_AccessMenu AM ,Temp_Menu TM  WHERE AM.[ParentID]=TM.[MenuID]        

  )   

  SELECT * FROM Temp_Menu ORDER BY ParentID
```