# Parent child relationship in Oracle

Tags: oracle, parent-child, recursive-query

I have a parent child relationship stored in a table 
consider the following example

```
Id        Name    ParentId
------------------------------
1         Node1      -1
2         Node2      -1
3         Node3       1
4         Node4       1
5         Node5       3
6         Node6       5
7         Node7       2
```

Here ParentId = -1 means that it is a root level node. Now I want to write an SQL Query which will return child at all level of a parent category.

e.g. for Id = 1, it should return 3, 4, 5, 6.

```
Parent     Child   
-------------------
1            3    
1            4    
1            5    
1            6
```

I am referring [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207309/sql-query-for-parent-child-relationship) but it is for sql-server and the output is not as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select parentid parent, id child
   from table1
connect by prior id = parentid
  start with parentid = 1
```