# Selecting children from an infinite hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an SQL table like this

```
ID    | ParentID
1     | null
2     | null
3     | null
4     | 1
5     | 4
6     | 5
7     | 6
8     | 7
9     | 8
```

Now, as you can see, a child parent relationship is maintained. I want a query to select "all level" children of a given ID.

Suppose if I input `ID = 1`, the result should be

```
ID    | ParentID
1     | null
4     | 1
5     | 4
6     | 5
7     | 6
8     | 7
9     | 8
```

So all immediate children, as well as children of their children at any level, should come up.

Is it possible to do this in MS SQL server? I have MS-SQL server 2012.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207309/sql-query-for-parent-child-relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example with an extra field Name, but with CTE the recursion is simple:

```
DECLARE @ID int

SET @ID = 1;

WITH CTE_Table_1
(
  ID,
  Name,
  ParentID,
  TreeLevel
)
AS(
 SELECT 
  ID,
  Name,
  ParentID,
  0 AS TreeLevel
 FROM Table_1
 WHERE ID = @ID

UNION ALL

 SELECT 
  T.ID,
  T.Name,
  T.ParentID,
  TreeLevel + 1
 FROM Table_1 T
 INNER JOIN CTE_Table_1 ON CTE_Table_1.ID = T.ParentID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE_Table_1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this workin fine : http://www.sqlteam.com/Forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=101053

```
-- Structure
create table dbo.MyPeople (Id int, Name varchar(30), ParentId int)

-- Data
insert dbo.MyPeople
          select 1, 'P1', null
union all select 2, 'P2', null
union all select 3, 'P1C1', 1
union all select 4, 'P1C2', 1
union all select 5, 'P2C1', 2
union all select 6, 'P1C2C1', 4
union all select 7, 'P1C1C1', 3
union all select 8, 'P1C1C1C1', 7
union all select 9, 'P2C1C1', 5
union all select 10, 'P1C3', 1
go

-- Function
create function dbo.AncestorPath(@Id int) returns varchar(100) as
begin
    declare @Path varchar(100)
    while 0 = 0
    begin
        select @Path = cast(Id as varchar(5)) + isnull('/' + @Path, ''), @Id = ParentId
        from dbo.MyPeople where Id = @Id

        if @@rowcount = 0 break
    end

    return @Path
end
go

-- Calculation
select * from (
    select *, dbo.AncestorPath(Id) as AncestorPath from dbo.MyPeople) a
where '/' + AncestorPath + '/' like '%/1/%'
```

or

Try recursive procedure like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetChildren
@ParentId int

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT * 
FROM MainTable 
WHERE ChildId IN 
(
SELECT ParentId 
FROM f_GetChildren(@ParentId)
UNION
SELECT ChildId
FROM f_GetChildren(@ParentId)
)
ORDER BY ParentId

SET NOCOUNT OFF
RETURN
```

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2005, [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) have been added to T-SQL of SQL Server that help you in this kind of hierarchial queries. That's what you are looking for!

Comment: Yes that could help me but don't know how to work on that, please provide some example.

Comment: Andras has given the CTE for this, I think you are good to go.