# How can I get linked list like (Parent - Child) mapped columns in a single Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, recursive-query

Consider The following Table

```
+--------+-------+--+
| Parent | Child |  |
+--------+-------+--+
|      1 |     2 |  |
|     10 |    13 |  |
|      2 |     3 |  |
|      3 |     4 |  |
|     13 |    14 |  |
|      4 |     5 |  |
|     15 |    16 |  |
|      5 |     1 |  |
+--------+-------+--+
```

In this table I'm following the hierarchy of parent child. From this table I want a result as the below table

```
+--------+-------+--+
| Parent | Child |  |
+--------+-------+--+
|      1 |     2 |  |
|      2 |     3 |  |
|      3 |     4 |  |
|      4 |     5 |  |
|      5 |     1 |  |
+--------+-------+--+
```

I want to get the hierarchy in my code **(1-2-3-4-5-1)**. At present I'm querying for each child after getting its parent (Sometimes, **Child can be any of previous Parents like 5-1**). For a long hierarchy it will execute a number of  queries. How can I make this more efficient?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query for Parent Child Relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207309/sql-query-for-parent-child-relationship)

Comment: @Jodrell I want something different. I have another parent in the table   which has its previous parent as its child again

Comment: That should never happen in any good design. It can be avoided but is a different question altogether. So even in your front end code, you'd have 1-2-3-4-5-1-2-3-4-5-1-2-3-4-5-etc because there's no end, an infinite loop.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi But if I need to store such a loop in Table , What should be the design then?

Comment: Justify why you would need to store such a loop?

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi I have a Content Management system. Suppose there are article sections a1,a2,a3. When user make an input to a1, I want to make it available to a2 and a3. If its a3, then a2 and a1. For this, I mapped a1 -> a2-> a3-> a1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @table as TABLE(Parent int, Child int)

insert into @table values
(1, 2),
(10, 13),
(2, 3),
(3, 4),
(13, 14),
(4, 5),
(5, 1)

select * from @table

declare @ParentID int
set @ParentID=1

;WITH T(Parent, Child)AS
    ( 
        SELECT Parent, Child from @table where Parent=@ParentID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT T1.Parent, T1.Child FROM @table T1 INNER JOIN T ON T1.Parent=T.Child
        WHERE T.Child<>@ParentID

    )
select * from T
order by Parent
```

Comment: I had a value like this also (5, 1). When I execute Query for this Table it will show invalid result. How can I exclude this condition???

Comment: Thank you for your apt solution

Comment: Can you tell me why this stored Procedure generates duplicates in the result set. http://pastie.org/7714494

Comment: I didn't get you... which one is the duplicate? Does it solve by using distinct (`select distinct * from T`)?

Comment: Thats solving the problem. But didn't get why its happening!

Comment: But the order seems to be different. How can I make it in an order? http://pastie.org/private/6oq5sduif5aahbdkfayihq

Answer (score 4):

```
;with cte(parent,child) as (
    select parent, child
      from sometable
     where parent = 1  --- seed
     UNION ALL
    select t.parent, t.child
      from sometable t
      join cte on cte.child = t.parent
)
    select *
      from cte;
```

To avoid infinite loops, you will have to store the list of traversed ids:

```
;with cte(parent,child,traversed) as (
    select parent, child, ',' + right(parent,10) + ','
      from sometable
     where parent = 1  --- seed
     UNION ALL
    select t.parent, t.child, cte.traversed + right(t.parent,10) + ','
      from sometable t
      join cte on cte.child = t.parent
     where not cte.traversed like ',%' + t.parent + '%,'
)
    select parent, child
      from cte;
```

But it won't run anywhere near as fast since it's having to do the LIKE checks.

Comment: I added this `(5 -     1 )` condition to my table. In my table I have this condition in real and this Query gives a different result here!

Comment: I have a Content Management system. Suppose there are article sections a1,a2,a3. When user make an input to a1, I want to make it available to a2 and a3. If its a3, then a2 and a1. For this, I mapped a1 -> a2-> a3-> a1.
What should I do in the above context? (the order is important)

Answer (score -1):

The manual covers that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx
SO really shouldn't be used to for asking questions that already have good answers in the manuals.

Comment: not true, its true that manuals shouldn't be used as answers but as references in answers.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168712/what-is-stack-overflows-take-on-link-only-answers

Comment: @Jodrell How about if I say it was already covered on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207309/sql-query-for-parent-child-relationship ? Looking for "sql server parent child" will bring up either of those two links therefore I believe the asker didn't put effort into his research.

Comment: That would be a valid comment and I'd be inclined to agree, see my vote.