# How to solve this error, The multipart identifier "column" could not be bound?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying out solution of [SQL Query for Parent Child Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207309/sql-query-for-parent-child-relationship) with the queries:

```
with [CTE] as (
    select [ParentId]
    , [NodeId]
    from [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = 1
    union all
    select [ParentId]
    , [NodeId]
    from [CTE] p, [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = p.[NodeId]
)
select * from [CTE]
```

the errors:

> The multipart identifier "p.[NodeId]" could not be bound
>
> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Not sure what to do next.

I expect it to return child at all level of a parent category.

e.g. for nodeId = 1, it should return 3, 4, 5, 6.

Comment: Why are you *still* using that ANSI-89 implicit JOIN syntax? The ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax has been around for **30 years** now. [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: You're using `SELECT *` so you are returning *more* columns in the bottom query; stop using `SELECT *` and get into the good habit of defining your columns. As for the former error, does your table `TheTable` (which you oddly alias as `c`) have a column called `NodeId`? If not, that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: ah, i see. i will select the column and try again.

Comment: hmm. this doesn't work.

Comment: "This doesn't work"? What is "this"? what is "doesn't work"?

Comment: *Now* you have ambiguous columns in your bottom query. `select [ParentId], [NodeId]` Is that "C" for `TheTable`'s `ParentId` or "P" for CTE's `ParentId`? Same for `NodeId`.

Comment: just update. the new queries, doesn't work same error occur.

Comment: Your link doesn't resolve to anything, but the first thing you need to do is confirm that just this works without error: `select [ParentId]  , [NodeId]  from [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from multiple columns with the same name occuring in two tables.

Both your table and the CTE contain `[ParentId]` and `[NodeId]`. So when this statement is executed:

```
select [ParentId], [NodeId] from [CTE] p, [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = p.[NodeId]
```

The `from` contains both the `[CTE]` and `[TheTable]` and SQL cannot resolve in the `SELECT` which table it should pull those columns from.  The link provided (copied and pasted, the link itself points to stackoverflow.com) uses * in the `SELECT` to give all columns and not worry about which table they originated from.

Either switch to a `SELECT *` style, or properly access the tables by table alias, i.e.:

```
select c.[ParentId], c.[NodeId] from [CTE] p, [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = p.[NodeId]
```

Add/Remove the specific table.column you'd like to `UNION`.

@Larnu Also points out correctly, the `JOIN` here is less than optimal.

Try:

```
select [ParentId], [NodeId] from [CTE] p INNER JOIN [TheTable] c ON c.[ParentId] = p.[NodeId]
```

I edited this because of a discussion with @Delta32000 where it's better to explicitly say `INNER JOIN` instead of `JOIN` even though they are functionally equivalent in T-SQL.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I don't think doing a `CROSS JOIN` here `[CTE] p, [TheTable]` is a good idea

Comment: @Delta32000 can you give some reasoning behind this?  I could go either way. I prefer a certain style but wouldn’t say the OP was wrong with their syntax.

Comment: @John is trying to do a recursive function here. In this case you want to `JOIN` on a certain condition. A `CROSS JOIN` will do a cartesian product betwin tables then keep only the correct row, that will lead to performances issues (what you don't want to see in a recursive function). The `INNER JOIN`, that don't do the cartesian product will be better in this solution. I think any query is wrong if it leads to performance issues.

Comment: @Delta32000 Thanks for clarifying!  I did need to ask because the `JOIN` statement is just an `INNER JOIN` and not a `CROSS JOIN` in T-SQL.  So I believe I was still ok, but I'll err on the side of being more explicit.

Comment: Yup you are right @Avogadro ! My bad if I haven't been clear about the fact that I was talking about the comma that means `CROSS JOIN` and not the `JOIN` for `INNER JOIN`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `[ParentId]` and `[NodeId]` in both `[CTE]` and `[TheTable]` so when you write

```
select [ParentId]
    , [NodeId]
    from [CTE] p, [TheTable] c where c.[ParentId] = p.[NodeId]
```

SQL Server doesn't know what `[ParentId]` and `[NodeId]` stands for (p or c)

You'd better write

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        TheTable.ParentId,
        TheTable.NodeId
    FROM TheTable WHERE TheTable.ParentId = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        TheTable.ParentId,
        CTE.NodeId
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN TheTable ON TheTable.ParentId = CTE.NodeId
)

SELECT * FROM CTE
```